# Setup VSCode and ts-standard

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, ts-standard

I have to set up `VScode` and `ts-standard`; I thought I did it successfully. In the project workspace, I added `.vscode/settings.json`

```
{
  "standard.engine": "ts-standard"
}
```

The issue is when I try to save a file, the decorator and the field are aligned to two spaces, and the error is

```
Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 2. (@typescript-eslint/indent)ts-standard(@typescript-eslint/indent)
```

The decorator should have two spaces and the field four.

It would probably work if I turned off the `onSave` trigger and manually corrected it. But I would like that this task is automatically computed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was the solution

I have to install this extension [StandardJS - JavaScript Standard Style](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=standard.vscode-standard)

Then, in the plugin extension settings

[image]

Switch the Standard: Engine to `ts-standard`

[image]

And leave my `settings.json`

```
{
  "standard.engine": "ts-standard"
}
```

What I was missing was the pluging